# File fails through X12 due to configuration of the Schema in the agreement

Tags: azure-logic-apps, edi, x12

I am currently attempting to run an EDI 835 Health Care Claim Payment/Advice file through a logic app. I have the file going through a Decode X12 message and it passes but its errors out when I create the XML file.

Error encountered during parsing. The X12 transaction set with id '000001145' contained in functional group with id '219001145', in interchange with id '921901136', with sender id '133052274      ', receiver id '391758640      ' is being suspended with following errors:
Error: 1 (Miscellaneous error)
    6: The message has an unknown document type and did not resolve to any of the existing schemas configured in the agreement.

I have double and triple checked the agreement that has my schema. Everything looks correct. I have even tried completely removing the schema from the agreement and I am still getting the same error. So I am beginning to think that the agreement is not attached properly.

This the Json I am currently using for the Schema Reference in the agreement.

```
                    "schemaReferences": [{
                            "messageId": "835",
                            "senderApplicationId": "HP",
                            "schemaVersion": "00501",
                            "schemaName": "X12_00501_835"
                        }],
```

Comment: Here is an [example](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5ef49ad9-8868-4bf3-931b-9ad32b554378/x12-error-during-schema-validation-of-edi-837-azure-logic-apps?forum=azurelogicapps) use EDI 837 which we can see the "schemaReferences" in it. Does this example help your issue ?